# looping a function not in sequence

Tags: loops, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scope

so I have this code to have multiple dependant drop-down lists in my google sheets. however, I want to apply this to almost 10 columns (not in order if possible) and want to know how I would loop the functions or have the variables more dynamic, so that i might simplify the code:

```
var dbSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ingredientDB);
var db= dbSheet.getRange(3,1,dbSheet.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
var firstColumn = 2;
var secondColumn = 3;
var thirdColumn = 4;


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  var rule= SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}//sets the data validation of a var=list(the options for ddl) to a var=cell (row of act cell in column wanted)

function onEdit(e){
  var actCell= e.range;
  var actCellVal= actCell.getValue();
  var row= actCell.getRow();
  var column= actCell.getColumn();
  var wsName= actCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName==recipeSheetName && column===firstColumn && row>1){
    apply1stLvlVal(actCellVal,row);
  }else if(wsName===recipeSheetName && column===secondColumn && row>1){
    apply2ndLvlVal(actCellVal,row);
  }
}//end onEdit

function apply1stLvlVal(actCellVal,row){
  var cell= recipeSheet.getRange(row,secondColumn);
  var cell3Col= recipeSheet.getRange(row,thirdColumn);
  if(actCellVal===''){
    cell.clear();cell.clearDataValidations();
    cell3Col.clear();cell3Col.clearDataValidations();
  }else {
    cell.clear();cell.clearDataValidations();
    cell3Col.clear();cell3Col.clearDataValidations();
    var filteredOptions= db.filter(function(o){return o [1]=== actCellVal});
    var list= filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o [2]});
    applyValidationToCell(list,cell);
  }
}//end apply1stLvlVal

function apply2ndLvlVal(actCellVal,row){
  var cell= recipeSheet.getRange(row,thirdColumn);
  if(actCellVal===''){
    cell.clear();cell.clearDataValidations();
  }else {
    cell.clear();cell.clearDataValidations();
    var firstLvlColValue= recipeSheet.getRange(row,firstColumn).getValue();
    var filteredOptions= db.filter(function(o){return o [1]=== firstLvlColValue && o[2]===actCellVal});
    var list= filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o [3]});
    applyValidationToCell(list,cell);
  }
}//end apply2ndLvlVal
```

`

if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: Take a look at this:https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs Take a look at the video at the bottom to see how it works

Comment: @Cooper. I'm still not yet skilled enough to understand that code. But thanks for the info

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is the question here. Would you mind providing more info and eventually give more details about what is not working in your code and what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @ale13. I want to pick an item from a database of items. Add data from certain columns of that data to my current sheet. I figured have different dropdowns to select/search for an item from that original dataset, while having each dropdown dependant on the choices of the other dropdowns was the best way to go. my issue was that for each data validation I would need a separate function. I wanted to know if I could create a single function that could handle all the data validations if the right variables were defined.

Comment: since all dropdowns would have to be completed in succession I'm now looking into a query function to handle this task.